# Metric Shader for VS 2010

Tags: c#, code-metrics

Has anyone found a Metric Shader type plugin for VS 2010? I was using a really good one in VS 2008 that is a plugin for Dev Express DXCore:

[Metric Shader](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_MetricShader)

But it doesn't work in VS 2010. I found this to be a tremendously handy tool while refactoring and would really like it 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of one, but that is pretty cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will certainly be upgrading the plugin to work with VS2010. The graphical subsystems of both VS2010 and CodeRush have been largely rewritten and this means that some of the older  GDI based dxcore APIs are no longer supported. I am currently looking at how best to reimplement this functionality. Watch this space ;)

Comment: Awesome, I look forward to it!

Comment: This is really an interesting addon. I clicked the example, but it has a rather unuseful metric! What are some real life useful metrics?

Comment: The plugin can use any installed metric. It also povides access to 3 other metrics which are provided with the CodeRush and CodeRush Xpress ('Cyclomatic Complexity', 'Maintenance Complexity' and 'Line Count'). 'Demo Metric' (only provided in case the user only has the raw DXCore installed) is essentially a duplicate of 'Line count'.

Comment: You may also craft you own metrics through the use of th DXCore